# HTML form submission in struts

Tags: struts

Can I submit a simple html form with html tags and no struts tags. I'm using struts 1.0 and have a form like this:

```
<form action='/admin/fsubmit.html?action=search' method='post'>
  <input type='text' name='keyword'>
  <input type='submit' name='search' value='Search'>
</form>
```

I'm handling this submission with struts. but it seems like my action is never called. Do I need to use form with struts html tags?

If using struts html tags is the only option then how do I use two forms in single Action class?

Comment: Is your action end with `.html` or `.do`?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes,

The problem I see here is your `action='/admin/fsubmit.html?action=search'`. It's either your action is mapped to a `.do` extension or `.html`. If it's the latter, then your relative URL isn't mapped properly.

Comment: Hey.. sorry..I found the problem. Actually I'm also using one ActionForm and one of it's property matches with that of this form and hence type error was there. but Still I want to know can I use tow ActionForms in same Action?

Comment: Nope, you can't specific 2 `name` fields in a Struts action.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi: Do you know if is it possible in struts 1.3 to use two nested forms (one for file upload)? I tried but also if the two forms have different actions, the second submit button doesn't work.

Comment: @Cricket, HTML specifications doesn't allow any nested forms at all. As I said earlier, one Struts `Ation` is linked to an `ActionForm`.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi: So the action to upload an attachment must be included to the "outer form" action and the inner form deleted. Thanks.